# Keeping multi-user state across DB sessions

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, web-applications, data-modeling

## The situation

Suppose we have a web application connected to a (Postgre)SQL database whose task can be summarized as:

1. A `SELECT` operation to visualize the data.
2. An `UPDATE` operation that stores modifications based on the visualized data.

Simple, but... the data involved isn't user specific, so it might potentially be changed during the process by other users. The editing task may take long time (perhaps more than an hour), meaning that the probability of these collisions happening isn't low: it makes sense to implement a robust solution to the problem.

## The approach

The idea would be that, once the user tries to submit the changes (i.e. firing the `UPDATE` operation), a number of database checks will be triggered to ensure that the involved data didn't change in the meantime.

Assuming we have timestamped every change on the data, it would be as easy as keeping the access time when the data was `SELECT`ed and ensuring that no new changes were done after that time on the involved data.

## The problem

We could easily just keep that access time in the frontend application while the user performs the editing, and later provide it as an argument to the trigger function when performing the `UPDATE`, but that's not desirable for security reasons. The database should store the user's access time.

An intuitive solution could be a `TEMPORARY TABLE` associated to the database session. But, again, the user might take a long time doing the task, so capturing a connection from the pool and keeping it idle for such a long time doesn't seem like a good option either. The `SELECT` and the `UPDATE` operations will be performed under different sessions.

## The question

Is there any paradigm or canonical way to address and solve this problem efficiently?

Comment: "so capturing a connection from the pool and keeping it idle for such a long time doesn't seem like a good option either"  How many such sessions do you expect to have ongoing at one time?

Comment: "but that's not desirable for security reasons"  Can you describe the security reasons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is known as the "lost update" problem.

There are several solutions that depend on whether a  connection pool is used or not  and on the [transaction isolation level](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/transaction-iso.html) used:

1. pessimistic locking with SELECT ... FOR UPDATE without connection pool
2. optimistic locking with timestamp column if connection pool is used.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! In fact, the reason why I didn't consider this as a classic "lost update problem' is because the read and write phases, strictly speaking, are not encapsulated into the same transaction but in two different transactions (even two different sessions). The 2nd approach you propose appears to be what I asked about, I'll take a look into it.